# How to have MySQL store TIMESTAMP but return timezone-aware datetime objects

Tags: mysql, datetime, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to have a `deleted_at` column on my records. I use MySQL and latest sqlalchemy as of writing. For historical reasons, I want to keep using MySQL's TIMESTAMP columns.

I would like to use timezone-aware datetime throughout my codebase. Everything in my DB is stored as UTC, so I don't really need to store the timezone. I just want to make sure the datetime is returned as a UTC-datetime.

```
import pytz
from sqlalchemy import Column, text, types
from sqlalchemy.dialects.mysql import TIMESTAMP as M_TIMESTAMP


# Fractional second precision
FSP = 6
TIMESTAMP = M_TIMESTAMP(fsp=FSP)
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP = text("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(%d)" % FSP)


class TimezoneAwareTimestamp(types.TypeDecorator):
    """Ensure tz-aware timestamp are returned."""


    impl = TIMESTAMP


    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        if not value:
            return None
        return value.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)


def DeletedAt():
    return Column("deleted_at", TimezoneAwareTimestamp, server_onupdate=text("0"),
                  nullable=True)
```

This is a pretty natural solution I came up with. Problem: `TimezoneAwareTimestamp` does not respect the `server_onupdate` attribute on creation. A table created with this `DeletedAt` column will show up as:

```
deleted_at` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
```

instead of (replacing `TimezoneAwareTimestamp` with `TIMESTAMP`):

```
deleted_at` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL
```

How can I have the custom type respect `server_onupdate` and `nullable`?

Thanks,

Charles

Comment: *"How to have MySQL store TIMESTAMP but return timezone-aware datetime objects"* Are you looking for MySQL 's [CONVERT_TZ()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz) function?

Comment: Nope - this is more about sqlalchemy than about MySQL...